# Missing last character when inserting new records mysql

Tags: php, mysql

New to php/mysql so please bear with me.

The code below is fed data by a form in the previous sheet. I do not get any error messages when inserting the records but when I check the table, the last character of the empno and buntg fields are missing. For empno, 0001 is displayed on screen but the value inserted in the table is 000. For buntg, 14000101 is displayed but 1400010 is inserted. No problem with opr tho.

```
<?php

$wopr = $_POST['operations'];
$empno = $_POST['empno2'];
$btg = $_POST['buntag2'];

echo $empno . "<br/>" . $btg . "<br/>" . $wopr . "<br/>";

$loaddat = "INSERT INTO ticket_data (empno,buntg,opr) VALUES ('$empno', '$btg', '$wopr')";

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test_database") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_query($loaddat) or die (mysql_error());
echo "Ticket Submitted. <br/> Ref. No: " . mysql_insert_id() . "<br/> Thank You.";
mysql_close();
?>
```

In ticket_data table, empno is varchar(4), buntg is varchar(8), opr is text. Collation is utf8_unicode_ci. When I dont use the variables and hardcode the values on $loaddat, they insert correctly, so I'm not sure if this has something to do with collation.

I am using XAMPP v.3.2.1 on windows 7. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Question was partially answered by the comments below. However, I still don't understand why I have to use different varchar lengths to insert the same data, but using different methods. Perhaps someone can enlighten me on this. Cheers!

Edit #2: I found that changing the varchar length works in inserting the data, but my validation methods now do not work. After changing the data type in all related tables, the query below now returns all occurrences of opr, regardless of the 'NOT IN' condition.

```
SELECT style_ops.opr FROM style_ops WHERE style_ops.style='$sty' AND style_ops.opr NOT IN (SELECT ticket_data.opr FROM ticket_data WHERE ticket_data.buntg='$btg')
```

When they were in varchar 4 and 8, everything works, except for the insert. Im reverting back to 4 and 8 and hoping that someone can address my original problem. Thanks again!

Edit#3: Problem solved. Thanks to a comment below, I looked at my input fields and found leading and trailing spaces on the form html code. Took them out and now its working sweet. Took note of SQLI and modified code accordingly.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the datatype of empno in  ticket_data table ?

Comment: empno is varchar with legnth of 4. thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting ticker_data table empno to varchar(5) and buntg to varchar(9)?

Comment: if both inputs are always numbers then convert fields to INT's rather than varchars

Comment: Yes you need to have the field type either big int or varchar with higher length.

Comment: INT worked but dropped the leading zeros. varchar 5 and 9 also worked. The reason I used an exact varchar length is to somehow control data entry. I guess controlling data entry should be done somewhere else. I'll use varchar 5 and 9 for now, but I would like to understand why varchar 4 and 8 works when I hardcode the numbers. Is there a leading space or blank when variables are used? thanks for the quick responses guys. Cheers!

Comment: I would suggest if you are using character fields to keep the leading zereos, try using trim. My guess would be that your input fields have a leading space. Oh, and your code is wide open to an sql injection attack.

Comment: Thanks kickstart for pointing me to the right direction. There are indeed leading and trailing spaces on my form HTML code. Took care of them and now everything works! Also, thanks for the warning about SQL injection. Did some research and I'll modify my code accordingly. Thanks again.